# Code two required condition in finding root with Fixed point method

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

I'm trying to find a root with simple fixed-point method by C++, but the point is that `Xr` is a root of `f(x)` and a inflection point as well. In addition, A equation is a little bit more complex than the normal Fixed-Point method.
The equation is added constant c for check how quickly converge to the root xr.

I was going to find a root and then check if the root is a inflection point or not, but it is not working and I can't find the problem in my code.
I need your help.

The real Problem is

Consider the root finding problem `f(x)=0` with root `xr`, with f`'(x)=0`.
Convert it to the simple fixed-point problem.

```
x=x+c*f(x)=g(x)
```

with c a nonzero constant. How should c be chosen to ensure rapid convergence of

```
x(n+1)=x(n)+c*f(x(n))  ( x(n+1) means the value of the n+1th of X )
```

to `c` (provided that `x0` is chosen sufficiently close to xr?). Apply your way of choosing c to the root-finding problem `x*x*x-5=0`. Start your program with `x0=1.0` and run with several values of c and discuss about the observed trend in your results (in other words, the effect of c value on convergence behavior)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double gx(double x, double c)
{
    return(x + c*(x*x*x - 5));
}

double gxpr(double x, double c)
{
    return(x + c*(3 * x*x));
}

void Simple_Fixed_Point(double x, double c) 
{
    int i = 1;
    long double x2=0.0;
    long double x3=0.0;
    long double ea=0.0;
    long double ea2 = 0.0;
    long double es = pow(10, -6);

    printf("Simple Fixed Point Method\n");

    Lbl:
        x2 = gx(x,c);

          printf("iteration=%d Root=%.5f Approximate error=%.15f\n", i++, 
x2, ea);

        if (ea=fabs((x2 - x)/x2*100) <es)
        {
            goto Lbm;
        }
        else
        {
            x = x2;
            goto Lbl;
        }

    Lbm:
        x3 = gxpr(x2, c);

        if (ea2 = fabs((x3 - x2) / x3 * 100) < es)
        {
            goto End;
        }
        else
        {
            x2 = x3;
            goto Lbm;
        }

    End:
         getch();
}

int main(void)
{
    Simple_Fixed_Point(1.0, 1.0);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: The function `f(x)=x^3-5` with `f'(x)=3x^2` has an inflection point at `x=0`, which however is not a root of `f`. Did you mean `f(x)=(x-5)^3`?

Comment: Please change your C++ code to work without `goto` statements. Please explain what role the function `gxpr` plays as the task tells nothing about the iteration `xnext=x+c*f'(x)`

Comment: Goto is great. Ignore the post above.

Comment: @LutzL Actually, As you told, that can not be accepted. However, when use the equation which is xnext=x+c*f(x), xr can be got.

Comment: @LutzL gxpr is to get a inflection point. I'd like to express g'(xr)=xr+c*f'(xr)

Comment: You are doing formula voodoo. Your task was to carry out the iteration `xnext = x + c*f(x)` for various parameters `c` and somehow measure the speed of convergence and based on these results speculate on where the range for the best `c` may lie. For simple roots the best parameters are around `c=-1/f'(xr)`, see Newton method. For roots of multiplicity `m` it is `c=-m/f'(xr)`. Unfortunately for the task your test function has only simple roots.

Comment: @AppWriter: In higher programming languages that have various facilities for structured programming, there are only very few cases where a `goto` is appropriate, the most prominent the escape from nested loops. C++ is not the 1980's BASIC.

Comment: @LutzL I just tried

Comment: @LutzL I just tried ohter way. I only considered the equation which is g(x)=x+c*f(x).

Comment: @LutzL: I was only trying to find a root xr. could you check my new code. it is not working either though.

Comment: The optimal `c` range for the single positive root `f(x)=x^3-5` at about `xr=1.71` is about `c=-0.114`. With `c=1` you can only expect divergence. In the range of `c=-0.2..-0.05` you get linear convergence, outside `-0.3..0.0` divergence, so the choice of `c` is rather critical.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
//f(x+dx) = f(x) + (dfdx) * dx;
eps = 1.0;    
dx = 1e-7; //something small
x = x0;
while (eps > mineps) {
  f1 = f(x);
  f2 = f(x + dx);      
  f3 = f(x + dx + dx);        
  d2fdx2 = (f3 - f2 - f2 + f1) / dx / dx;
  dfdx = (f2 - f1) / dx;
  x -= (relax1 * f1 / dfdx + relax2 * dfdx / d2fdx2); //relax - something less 1
  eps = max(abs(dfdx), abs(f1));
}
```